# Angulartics tracking event missing

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, angulartics, intercom

I'm using angulartics with google analytics and intercom. 
In my current case i have to track the same event multiple times in a loop,but angulartics seems to throw the events away if they occure to fast successively.

When using the debugger, each event is tracked, also if i call the eventTrack with some delay for each event.
But without debugger and delay the event is only tracked once.

Am i missing anything or is this exactly what is recommended, delaying the track-call?

Code-Example:

```
// looping a list of things you want to track for each element
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
  // call the event tracks in parallel, 
  // fired async with a delay of 1000 ms between each  
  setTimeout(function delayed() {
     $analytics.eventTrack(action, trackingEvent);
  }, 1000 * i);
}
```

Comment: Thing you describe seems like debounce method or something similar. It is designed as protection against overloading, e.g. scroll events are very noisy and if every single callback will be processed, it will shut down the browser (or slow down at least). Try to calm down you event emittor.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, makes sense to debounce in case of scroll events etc. However in my case its a batch operation i want to track as single events, e.g. sending a mail to multiple contacts - for each contact a mail-send-event is tracked. Something like $analytics.eventTrack(<eventName>, <amount>), where amount is the number of times the event should be tracked, would be a good idea to cover that case.

Comment: Until you do not show bigger part of your code, is hard to help you. You are using client side or server side solution? Angularitics is only wrapper above analytics tools, what connector do you use? Please, extend your question.